# I want To Add Data in An Array On Runtime

Tags: ios

Here is my code :

```
NSData *result = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials"]];
TFHpple *xpath = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:result]; //use xpath to search element
data = [xpath searchWithXPathQuery:@"//div[@class='content-wrapper']/ul/li/a"];
title = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (TFHppleElement *item in data)
{   //write log
    NSLog(@"Title : %@", item.content);
    NSLog(@"URL : %@", [item.attributes valueForKey:@"href"]);
    NSLog(@"-------------------------------");

    [title addObject:item.content];
//  [title addObject:getdata(item.content)];

}
```

Comment: We can't tell you with just this, what do you got in your output ?

Did you initialize your data ? did you debug to get what is inside data ?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that code, please describe your issue or what you are trying to do.

Comment: What is the type of item.content?

Comment: Most probably you are trying to add nil to array. It won't work

Comment: @NaXir - item.content hold a String and  After One Cycle Completion014-05-15 15:07:30.324 HtmlParser[2313:a0b] -------------------------------
2014-05-15 15:07:30.324 HtmlParser[2313:a0b] Title : Learn to Code iOS Apps 2: Strings, Arrays, Objects and Classes
2014-05-15 15:07:30.325 HtmlParser[2313:a0b] URL : http://

Comment: @NaXir 2014-05-15 15:19:59.992 HtmlParser[2400:a0b] Title : Learn to Code iOS Apps 2: Strings, Arrays, Objects and Classes

Comment: BTW you can add a check at its top, if string exists then add to array. Its crashing or what?

Comment: Place check if(item.content) before [title addObject:item.content];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if( data != nil )
    {
        for (TFHppleElement *item in data)
        {   //write log
            if( item != nil )
            {
                NSLog(@"Title : %@", item.content);

```
            NSLog(@"URL : %@", [item.attributes valueForKey:@"href"]);

            NSLog(@"-------------------------------");

            if (item.content!=nil) {

                [title addObject:item.content];

            }
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"item is nil");
        }
    }
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"data is nil");
   // [title addObject:nil];
}
```